# tar: /backup/backup.tar: Cannot open: Permission denied al hacer una copia de seguridad de un volumen de datos Docker

Tags: docker

Quiero copiar los datos que créé con neo4j. Entonces sigué [la documentacion](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-migrate-data-volumes) pero mientras que he dado la contrasena hay una error de permisiones:

```
bash-5.1$ sudo docker run --rm --volumes-from zoologie -v $(pwd):/backup neo4j tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /data
[sudo] password for ac: 
grep: /var/lib/neo4j/conf/neo4j.conf: No such file or directory
tar: /backup/backup.tar: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Con este comando queria:

- Lanzar un nuevo contenedor y montar el volumen desde el contenedor data
- Montar un directorio local del host como /backup
- Pasar un comando que tar el contenido del volumen dbdata a un archivo backup.tar dentro de nuestro directorio /backup.

Comment: Pues ahí lo único raro es que usas `pwd` para decirle qué directorio mapear a `backup` en el contenedor. Es posible que estés corriendo esto desde un directorio en el que root no puede escribir? Qué pasa si lo ejecutas ubicado en otro directorio?

Answer (score 0):

Pues ahí lo único raro es que usas `pwd` para decirle qué directorio mapear a `backup` en el contenedor. Es posible que estés corriendo esto desde un directorio en el que root no puede escribir? Qué pasa si lo ejecutas ubicado en otro directorio (ej `/root`)?

Lo otro: ya que tienes Fedora, prueba que SELinux no esté haciendo bromas, prueba usando `setenforce 0` y corriéndolo de nuevo...